# Mongoose Aggregation Returning Empty Array

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some issues aggregating collections with mongoose and a little confused what I am doing wrong. For context here is how my schemas are setup with response examples:

Skill:

```js
const SkillSchema: Schema = new Schema<Skill>({
  Skill: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

```json
{
  "_id": "627092699d087d0e7db4f359",
  "Skill": "AdSense Tracker",
  "Date": "2022-05-03T02:23:01.611Z"
}
```

UserSkill:

```js
const UserSkillSchema: Schema = new Schema<UserSkill>({
  userID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  skillID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "62a39c6f2a73b0cc3af71e56",
    "userID": "625decf49b367400701f6f67",
    "skillID": "627092699d087d0e7db4f359"
  },
  {
    "_id": "62a39c6f2a73b0cc3af71e58",
    "userID": "625decf49b367400701f6f67",
    "skillID": "627092699d087d0e7db4f35c"
  },
  {
    "_id": "62a39c702a73b0cc3af71e5a",
    "userID": "625decf49b367400701f6f67",
    "skillID": "627092699d087d0e7db4f35d"
  }
]
```

I've been trying to create an aggregation between my userSkills collection and my skills collection so that I am able to get all the names of the skills a user has rather than just the skillID. I setup my function like this:

```js
UserSkillModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "skills",
      localField: "skillID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "skill",
    },
  },
]).exec((err: CallbackError, userSkills: Skill[]) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
  res.status(200).send(userSkills);
});
```

But for some reason, I am getting an empty array for skill which I expect to be the skill associated to the skillID from the skills collection. This is what my current response looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "62a39c6f2a73b0cc3af71e56",
    "userID": "625decf49b367400701f6f67",
    "skillID": "627092699d087d0e7db4f359",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62a39c6f2a73b0cc3af71e58",
    "userID": "625decf49b367400701f6f67",
    "skillID": "627092699d087d0e7db4f35c",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62a39c702a73b0cc3af71e5a",
    "userID": "625decf49b367400701f6f67",
    "skillID": "627092699d087d0e7db4f35d",
    "__v": 0,
    "skill": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm very confused here as I feel like this should be setup correctly but I'm assuming its a small mistake causing this problem. So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

From the comment thread with [R2D2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72579543/mongoose-aggregation-returning-empty-array/72579737#72579737) I was able to see that the code works perfectly fine in Mongo Playground but for whatever reason doesn't seem to work in my application. The only thing I can think of is that I am using the schema for the aggregate function but I can't figure out why this wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you provide wrong collection name in the lookup , but the aggregation query is ok in general , check the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/66QM4zVQhq_)

Comment: I'm assuming you're referencing the `from` part of the lookup? If so, what should that be?

Comment: you say that the name is "Skill" , but in the from part you type it as "skills" , perhaps is just a typo ...

Comment: `skills` in the from section is the name of the collection. Is that not what it should be?

Comment: as you can see the agg. query in the playground is working as expected ...

Comment: Hmm, seems like you're right. Is it possible that because in my collection that skill id looks like `_id: ObjectId("627092699d087d0e7db4f359")` There are some implications?